# How convert string of separate words to separate elements of list by using stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Try to studying Stream API.
So, I have a list of strings like this:

```
118.111.97.113
119.122.122.122
122.122.122.97
122.122.122.99
122.122.122.100
```

I need to split it by '`.`' and separate numbers put as separate value to new collection.
Like this:

```
118
111
97
113
119
...
```

I know about `flatMap` method, that can assume one value and return several, but how use it correctly, have no one idea. Can you help me or give some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: think of `flatMap` as squeezing a fruit with seeds, you get one fruit as input and lots of seeds as output

Comment: @Eugene Ooooh!!! Delicious!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do

```
List<String> initial;
List<String> all = initial.stream().flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("\\.")))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Eugene `"\\."` is a single character delimiter for which `String.split` will not create a `Pattern` at all.

Comment: @Holger isn't that an internal detail? :)

Comment: @Eugene Not different to assuming that creating a `Pattern` each time is expensive or that there is no `Pattern` cache behind `String.split`. Sometimes, when you have to make a choice between two equivalent variants, you have to consider what is reasonable to expect from implementations and what the common implementation(s) actually do…

Comment: @Eugene I did some quick test, list ok 100k elem, 50iterations, and it's not quicker at all to build the pattern before, even sometimes it's slower

Comment: @azro then this is a problem of some warm-up I guess, not an indication of which is slower/faster

Answer (score 5):

Something alone the lines of:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
yourStreamOfStrings.flatMap(p::splitAsStream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```